# Who should teach the mathematics subjects in the engineering curriculum?

Tags: mathematics-education

Should mathematics courses in Engineering Degree Programs, particularly those which are covered in licensure examinations, be taught by someone whose background is mathematics, or by someone whose background is engineering?

Comment: This question is way too vague as stated to lead to a meaningful discussion. In particular, my usual complaint: unless the question is *localized*, i.e. references a specific educational system, it lacks the necessary context to make cogent arguments.

Comment: I agree with Thierry Zell's comment, and would also add that the current phrasing of the question is too subjective.